# Problems turning off Oculus Rift - it keeps thinking my app is still using it

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx, oculus

I'm making a C# WPF application with Oculus Rift integration using the (now obsolete) OculusWrap Oculus SDK adapter and SharpDX.

Recently, my application started to have issues when turning off. While running, everything works well. But after stopping Oculus usage, the last submitted frame keeps being displayed and Oculus Home says my application is "Now Playing". Even though it's already turned off. 
Sometimes instead of the last frame, a hourglass symbol is displayed in the headset.

I have gone through [the documentation](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-render/#dg-render-distortion) and as far as I see, all my `ovr_...Create` are matched with their `ovr_...Destroy` counterparts. Both `ovr_Destroy` and `ovr_Shutdown` are also called after everything is done.

When I try to restart Oculus use, it works well - until I try to turn it off again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked the [question on the Oculus Developer Forums](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/63126/problems-turning-off-oculus-rift-it-keeps-thinking-my-app-is-still-using-it#latest) and got my answer:

> *Kersk, Oculus staff:*
>   Try using the "ovrInit_MixedRendering" flag on the ovrInitParams Flags field passed in to ovr_Initialize(). It allows apps to toggle between 2D and VR.

TL;DR: `initParams |= 0x20` works.